# New thread for each object in array not outputting or joining

Tags: ruby, multithreading

```
array = ["1","2"]
array.each do |arrayobj|
    Thread.new {
        puts "#{arrayobj}"
    }
    Thread.join
end
```

Hello! I am probably doing something very simply wrong, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Thank you in adv.

Comment: Consider using the `parallel` gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel

Answer (score 2):

`join` is a method on an instance of `Thread`, not the `Thread` class itself.

You need to create a collection of threads and then call `join` on each one.

```
array.map do |i| 
  Thread.new { puts i }
end.map(&:join)
```

The first `map` will map the inputs, `array`, to an array of threads, the second `map`, will then call `join` on each thread, its expanded form is `.map { |thread| thread.join }`.

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html

Here is another example to better illustrate it working:

```
array = (1..100).to_a
array.map { |i| Thread.new { sleep(rand); puts i } }.map(&:join)
# => 97
31
75
36
50
53
17
81
49
35
83
11
13
24
29
7
.. etc.
```